# Matching the same lines from 2 different files and 2 columns

Tags: r, linux, merge, match, multiple-columns

I have two files, and I would like to merge them based on the first two columns, if the lines match, and add the third column of file2 to file1.

File1

```
CHR BP SNP ZSCORE
1   2534 rs123 0.5
1   2860 rs225 0.1
1   10000 rs356 0.8
```

File2

```
CHR BP AF
1   2534 0.02
1   6538 0.1
1   12345 0.1
```

What I want is:

File3

```
CHR BP SNP ZSCORE AF
1   2534 rs123 0.5 0.02
```

I tried R's `merge()`, but it led to just adding the columns together in the new dataset:

```
merged<-merge(File1, File2, by.x = "BP", by.y = "CHR", all = TRUE)
merged<-merge(File1, File2, by.x = "CHR", by.y = "BP", all = TRUE)
```

The next `merge()` I tried:

```
merged <- merge(File1[c('CHR','BP')],File2)
```

produced additional rows, which I don't think it's correct. How can matching a file of 17 million rows against the file of 17,200,000 rows produce 18,000,000 rows?!

Tried dplyr left join:

```
merged<-dplyr::left_join(File1, File2, by = c("CHR", "BP"))

Warning message:
In dplyr::left_join(File1, File2, by = c("CHR", "BP")) :
  Detected an unexpected many-to-many relationship between `x` and `y`.
ℹ Row 5 of `x` matches multiple rows in `y`.
ℹ Row 3570136 of `y` matches multiple rows in `x`.
ℹ If a many-to-many relationship is expected, set `relationship = "many-to-many"` to silence this warning.
```

Reversing the files led to the same error.

I also tried various versions of awk and join, but didn't produce what I wanted.

If anyone knows the solution, please let me know, doesn't matter whether it's an R solution, or awk/join-all.

Comment: `by.x` and `by.y` reference the column names in `x=` (the first frame) and `y=` (second frame) respectively, they aren't supposed to reference column-name-1 and column-name-2. `merge(File1, File2, by = c("CHR", "BP"))` gives your expected output, without `all=`.

Comment: Hi, thanks, however, this produced the same output as my previously written command:merged <- merge(File1[c('CHR','BP')],File2)
This output gives me 18,500,000 rows-how is that possible?

Comment: `merge(File1, File2, by = c("CHR", "BP"))` and `merge(File1[c('CHR','BP')],File2` produce different outputs for me, not sure why you say they're the same output. Your `File3` is produced by the first expression. BTW, your expected output suggests an `inner_join`, not a left/right/full join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the input in the Note at the end

**1) merge**  This uses base R `merge`

```
merge(File1, File2, by = 1:2)
##   CHR   BP   SNP ZSCORE   AF
## 1   1 2534 rs123    0.5 0.02
```

**2) inner_join** This uses dplyr `inner_join`:

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(File1, File2, join_by(CHR, BP))
##   CHR   BP   SNP ZSCORE   AF
## 1   1 2534 rs123    0.5 0.02
```

**3 sqldf** If the files are too large it can be done outside of R provided the result is still small enough for R using sqldf:

```
# create test files
write.csv(File1, "File1.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(File2, "File2.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
rm(File1, File2)

sqldf("select * from File1 inner join File2 using (CHR, BP)", 
  dbname = tempfile())
##   CHR   BP   SNP ZSCORE   AF
## 1   1 2534 rs123    0.5 0.02
```

**4) qsv**  Another way to do it outuside of R is to use the [qsv](https://github.com/jqnatividad/qsv/releases) utility.  Assuming the same setup as for `sqldf`

```
library(data.table)
fread("qsv join CHR,BP File1.csv CHR,BP File2.csv")
##    CHR   BP   SNP ZSCORE CHR   BP   AF
## 1:   1 2534 rs123    0.5   1 2534 0.02
```

### Note

```
Lines1 <- "
CHR BP SNP ZSCORE
1   2534 rs123 0.5
1   2860 rs225 0.1
1   10000 rs356 0.8e"

Lines2 <- "CHR BP AF
1   2534 0.02
1   6538 0.1
1   12345 0.1"

File1 <- read.table(text = Lines1, header = TRUE)
File2 <- read.table(text = Lines2, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you! However, my files have 17 million rows each. Is it the right way to add them as a note?

Comment: That is just to keep the answer self contained. You can just use ordinary `read.table` or `read.csv` commands to read them into R. If you find you don't have enough memory then have added an `sqldf` solution which will perform the entire join in a temporary database. outside of R returning the result to R. –Have also added a `qsv` solution which will do the merge outside of R.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I found a solution with `awk`:

```bash
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]=$3;next} ($1,$2) in a{print $0, a[$1,$2]}' File1 File2 > merged
```